# Unique function/variable

Tags: javascript, yui

I have a web application that opens multiple tabs using Ajax and in those tabs there is some JavaScript functions and variables. 
What's the best approach to make the functions and variables unique, so I don't call the function from a different tab or update an element that has the same name.

Comment: If you use namespaces and don't pollute the global scope, you'll be fine. Read up on these results and find a method that you like: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+pollute+global+namespace&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS527US527&aq=0&oq=javascript+pollute+&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l3.3945j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

The only approach would be to use [iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2Fiframe). You can either use iframes instead of Ajax, or you can load content from Ajax and insert it into an iframe. YUI Has a Frame class that may help you do that.

Comment: Judging != answering. He may want to load third party code. We don't know.